# C++ multithreaded test harness cannot verify responses without use of mutex lock around request

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am attempting to write a test harness to assess the throughput of a TCP server I have also written. Essentially the harness allows you to configure the number of threads you want to use, and then the threads will each run the function below in parallel. I need to verify that the server responses are correct, but the only way I can see to do it is by locking a mutex around the line that sends the request, because without this there is a chance that the server will process a request from a different thread before the one sent from the current. There is no issue with the server I do not believe, but the time in between receiving the response and storing it means that some of the responses are out by 1.

The server essentially allows you to post messages to the server and then it will respond with the index of that message. I need to find some way of avoiding locking around the request line, because this means the number of requests I can send will be limited.

```
void postRequest(string serverIp, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs)
{
    TCPClient client(serverIp, DEFAULT_PORT);
    client.OpenConnection();

    int threadPostCount = 0;
    double timeSpan;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    do 
    {
        // TODO: Add throttling
        string request = requestGenerator->generateWriteRequest();
        PostRequest post = PostRequest::parse(request);
        //mLock.lock();
        string response = client.send(request);
        //mLock.unlock();
        db->addPosterValue(0, post.getTopicId(), post.getTopicId(), response);
        threadPostCount++;

        endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        timeSpan = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(endTime - startTime).count();
    } while (timeSpan < timeDurationSecs);

    double totalRunTime = (endTime - startTime).count();
    double posterRequestsPerSecond = threadPostCount / timeSpan;
    tuple<double, double> returnValues = make_tuple(timeSpan, posterRequestsPerSecond);

    mLock.lock();
    postRequests += threadPostCount;
    posterThreadMap[threadIndex] = returnValues;
    mLock.unlock();

    client.CloseConnection();
}
```

The following code represents the data structure responses are stored in (which is shared across all threads)

```
map<string, vector<tuple<string, string>>> topicToMessagesWithResponse;
```

The method that adds the response to this is as follows:

```
void Storage::addPosterValue(int postIndex, string topicId, string message, string response)
{
    lock.lock();
    this->topicToMessagesWithResponse[topicId].push_back(make_tuple(message, response));
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning. I also don't see any data structure that is shared between other runs of above function from different threads. Could you add a sketch that shows what pieces could be executed by two threads causing issues?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have updated it to show the data structure

Comment: That seems guarded by a lock. Only problem I see is that it doesn't use RAII, but that's not an issue here. Still, I don't see a problematic scenario from your description.